# How to use struct in this case

Tags: c, struct

The code:

```
struct result
{
  char won[MAX_NAME_LEN+1];
  char lost[MAX_NAME_LEN+1];
};

void add_to_scoreboard(struct result * scoreboard, 
struct result * latest_game)
{
  if (latest_game = struct result * won)
    {

    }
}
```

When I try to compile this I get the error:

```
error: expected expression before ‘struct’
 if (latest_game = struct result * won)
```

I am new to c programming and I am trying to make it so that if a players result in the last game was a win they will be added to the scoreboard as a winner and the loser of that round be added on the scoreboard as a loser. Am I missing something in the code or is there another way I should be writing this all together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `won` property of `latest_game` with `latest_game->won`
rather than `latest_game = struct result * won`